# Какие способы создания модульного desktop-приложения существуют?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В ходе разработки приложения возник вопрос, какие способы есть поделить приложения на модули, чтобы при установке пользователь мог выбрать какой-то набор и ему установился бы только этот набор модулей.

Вопрос вдохновлен установщиком VS и аналогичными.

Пока прилетел совет посмотреть MEF, но это, как будто, про внутреннюю организацию приложения

Comment: Вы, в любом случае, часть функциональности, будете выносить в библиотеки, ну и устанавливайте только те библиотеки которые пользователю будут нужны :) .

Comment: А смысл? Вы разрабатываете приложение на десятки Гигабайт? Что в результате дадут ваши трудозатраты на разработку такой архитектуры?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно и как вы хотите там сделать. Если "модуль" для вас это несколько строк кода, которые выполняются с одним интерфейсом, одними командами, и все у них одно, то достаточно просто загрузить dll, все... Ну а если модуль, это полноценное "приложение", со своим функционалом, интерфейсом, и прочим, то это весьма не простая задачка, ибо надо для начала весь функционал разбить на абстракции, а потом их реализовывать помодульно. Подобное кстати есть [в Prism](https://brianlagunas.com/prism-dynamically-discover-and-load-modules-at-runtime/).

Comment: @rotabor интересно, как пишутся такие приложения. Например пользователю нужен один функционал, но не нужен другой и интересует именно возможность конфигурировать приложение при установке.

Answer (score 0):

Если в познавательном плане, то:

- Если функция реализована в отдельном приложении, то оно либо устанавливается, либо нет.
- Если это какая-то интегрированная среда, то можно отображать/скрывать или делать недоступными меню и команды (и др. элементы управления) согласно конфигурационному файлу. Или не скрывать, но выдавать пользователю информацию, что данная функция недоступна с указанием причины. Программа не будет обращаться к каким-то библиотекам (dll) или приложениям, и их можно не устанавливать.